# How to define directory for compiled files with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel-mix

I am using Mix version 4.0.14, and I'm updating a project to place all compiled files into a specific directory. Initially, everything went into the `public/` directory, but I now want all compiled files to go into `public/assets/` to keep things tidy.

I could update all the paths in `webpack.mix.js` and add `assets/` to the path, search my code where I've used `mix()`, and add `assets/` to the path there.

Is there a cleaner way? For example, can I define `assets/` somewhere that Mix knows to compile into that directory and then add the directory to the path when the assets are called? I've spent some time searching but no luck so far.

Comment: Laravel Mix is currently at v4.0.15.

Comment: @KarlHill - updated. I ran `npm laravel-mix --version` which gave me the wrong info, `npm list laravel-mix` was what I needed